# Reduce button's size cut the image instead of reduce size

Tags: html, css, button, size

I have a table with 2 columns: on the right one threre's some text and on the left one there's a button with image in it (some blue gradient) and a text. The image is in css file (it have to be this way).

[image]

When I change the width or height of the button (percentage) it doesn't reduce the image size but cutting it.

How can I make it reduce the size of the image?

```
Html:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            hello hello
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="address">
            My name is<br>
            Inigo Montoya
        </td>
        <td style="width: 35%;">
            <button class="button-background" type="button">
                update</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

css:
    button.button-background
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0g==');
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        border: transparent;
        color: white;
    }
```

Comment: Use `background-size`. But are you sure the data url is OK? When I put that in a fiddle it doesn't show anything.

Comment: "background-size: contain" did the job. The url is a blue image

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the image responsive so that it will fit inside the div/td width. For an image to be responsive add a class to image.

```
.image-responsive{
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Misspelled while typing.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello Hello</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="address">
            My name is<br>
            Inigo Montoya
        </td>
        <td style="width: 55%;">
            <button class="button-background" type="button">
                update</button>
        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.button-background
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url('http://wallpapers.free-   review.net/wallpapers/12/Abstract_Temporary_collapse.jpg');
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color:white;
    }
```